# How do I avoid a redundant trailing newline when concatenating two files?

Tags: c++

I want to merge two files into one file and when I do it at the end of the my merged file there is an extra blank line, How can I delete it?

file1 contains:

```
1  2  3
```

and file2 contains:

```
4  5  6
```

the the merged file is like

```
1  2  3
4  5  6
<------cursor is here
```

here is my code:

```
ifstream read1("1.txt");
ifstream read2("2.txt");

ofstream write ("3.txt");

string line;
string line2;

while ( getline ( read1, line, '\n' ) )
{
 if (!line.empty())
  write << line << endl;
}

while ( getline ( read2, line2, '\n' ) )
{
 if (!line2.empty())
  write << line2 << endl;
}

read1.close();
read2.close();
write.close();
```

Comment: (1) Don't use `endl` unless you explicitly need the content flushed to disk. And you don't. Use `write << '\n';` (2) You always add a new line at the end of a write operation, so perhaps adding it at another point in the operation is in order.

Comment: I'd prefer to have newlines at the end of all the files (some code / programs seems to deal with this better). Is there a reason you don't want the end of the file on a new line?

Comment: Check for `read2.eof()` before writing newline in the ` write << line2 << endl`

Comment: What is with the checks of `empty`?  If the string is `emtpy` the read failed and the loop wouldn't execute anyways.

Comment: @Marek [Nope!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: @NathanOliver -- you get an empty string when the input contains a blank line. That's not a read failure.

Comment: @PeteBecker Ah yes.  I didn't see empty lines in there example but they might have them.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ and what about situations where original input will contain newline at the end too?

Comment: Formally, both C and C++ **require** writing a newline to the end of a text file. Not having one means that programs that read such a file can fail on some systems. Granted, that's not very common (if I remember correctly, this was an issue for MVS, an ancient mainframe block-oriented file system), but there's usually no good reason for building in non-portabilities.

Comment: @Marek OP already checks that with `if (!line2.empty())`. No need for `eof()`.

Comment: @PeteBecker And AFAICT, whether the OP's editor displays an empty line at the end, as a result of the trailing newline, is a function of how it renders. `vim` does not for example, but something like Notepad IIRC does.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ In fact it is. He has two files containing no newline at the end. When he reads last line there might and might not be newline. Hence the check for EOF as we have to distinguish whether the read ended by EOF or  by newline.

Comment: Any reasons to read line by line ?

Answer (score 1):

Using the [`streambuf` overload for `operator<<`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) we can do:

```
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream read1("1.txt");
    std::ifstream read2("2.txt");
    std::ofstream write("3.txt");
    write << read1.rdbuf() << '\n' << read2.rdbuf();
}
```

Comment: Not only it removes any newline, but also adds extra newline

Comment: @k-five It seems to me that the objective is to merge two files, not filter out newlines. Granted, the code in question does filter out newlines and then add back its own newlines as separators, but that seems like a means to an end which was not completely working for OP. Clearly the input files are records separated by newlines and the desired output is records separated by newlines. We only require a newline between the files to separate the adjacent records and we're done.

Comment: I thought `if (!line.empty()) write << line << endl; ` is **filter out newlines**. What does it mean?

Comment: @k-five Yes, I agree with you that the provided code does filter out newlines. This answer works under the assumption that it was not a requirement, but perhaps an attempt to avoid the newline at the end. The question could be clearer and the sample data doesn't clarify. OP is welcome to choose the answer that works best.

Answer (score 0):

Before the second while read the first line, write it to the file and then 
use the while as you do but enter a new line first.
Something like this:

```
getline(read2 , line2, '\n');
if (!line2.empty()) 
   write << line2;

while ( getline ( read2, line2, '\n' ) )
{
 if (!line2.empty())
  write << endl <<line2;
}
```

This is not exactly what you ask but it should do the trick.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I only got one loop. What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Test for end of input file and don't put additional newline at the end.
Change

```
write << line2 << endl;
```

to

```
{
    write << line2;
    if (!read2.eof()) {write << "\n";}
}
```

**EDIT:** I have added curly braces to compensate for your single line IF's. Please try to avoid it in your code. See how [George](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44825456/8113019) easily fell into that trap.

Answer (score 0):

<< endl will flush the buffer and add a '\n'
You can think of it was being equivalent to adding a '\n' at the end, for added simplicity.

If you want to never add a newline just write the code as:
    ifstream read1("1.txt");
    ifstream read2("2.txt");

```
ofstream write ("3.txt");

string line;
string line2;

while ( getline ( read1, line, '\n' ) )
{
 if (!line.empty())
  write << line;
}

while ( getline ( read2, line2, '\n' ) )
{
 if (!line2.empty())
  write << line2;
}

read1.close();
read2.close();
write.close();
```

If you wish to write a newline after every line in the fact except the last line of the last file than buffer the thing into a string and write that to the file... not the most efficient option maybe, but good enough:

```
ifstream read1("1.txt");
ifstream read2("2.txt");

ofstream write ("3.txt");

string line;
string line2;
string buffer
while ( getline ( read1, line, '\n' ) )
{
 if (!line.empty())
  buffer += line;
  buffer += "\n";
}

while ( getline ( read2, line2, '\n' ) )
{
 if (!line2.empty())
        buffer += line2;
        buffer += "\n";
}

//Remove the last char from buffer (the '\n' bothering you)
buffer.substr(0, myString.size()-1)
write << buffer;

read1.close();
read2.close();
write.close();
```

Marek Vitek's answer is actually better than mine:

```
ofstream write ("3.txt");

string line;
string line2;

while ( getline ( read1, line, '\n' ) )
{
 if (!line.empty())
  write << line << endl;
}

while ( getline ( read2, line2, '\n' ) )
{
 if (!line2.empty()) {
  write << line2 
 } 
 if(!line2.empty() && !read2.eof() {
  write << line2 << endl;
 } 
}

read1.close();
read2.close();
write.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about raw copy:

```
std::ifstream read1{path1};
read1.unsetf(std::ios_base::skipws);
std::ifstream read2{path2};
read2.unsetf(std::ios_base::skipws);
std::ofstream write{path3};

std::copy(std::istream_iterator<char>(read1),
          std::istream_iterator<char>(),
          std::ostream_iterator<char> (write));

write << '\n'; // extra EOL between file

std::copy(std::istream_iterator<char>(read2),
          std::istream_iterator<char>(),
          std::ostream_iterator<char> (write));
```

Answer (score -1):

Another short solution (though I don't know what should be wrong with the final newline in the merged result):

```
ifstream read1("1.txt");
ifstream read2("2.txt");

ofstream write ("3.txt");

string line;
string line2;

do {
    if (!line.empty())
       write << line << '\n';
} while( getline ( read1, line, '\n' ) )
write.flush();

do {
    if(!line2.empty())
        write << line2;
} while( getline ( read2, line2, '\n' ) && write << `\n`);

read1.close();
read2.close();
write.close();
```

Comment: @Jarod THX for fixing

Comment: This way you are killing newline even if it was present in the original file. But maybe it is what OP wants. He just wanted to remove extra blank line IMHO.

Comment: @marek Well, it replicates exactly the output OPs getting from their actual code, except the last newline which they said is not wanted.

Comment: I agree, twith input he provided it will make no difference. But when there will be newline at the end of 2.txt then our solutions will give different results. Yours will be one character short.

Answer (score -1):

#### merge two file that has extra newline

```
std::ifstream ifs_1( "file1" );
std::ifstream ifs_2( "file2" );

std::ofstream ofs( "file3" );

for( std::string line; std::getline( ifs_1, line ); ){
    if( line != "" ){
        ofs << line << '\n';
    }
}
for( std::string line; std::getline( ifs_2, line ); ){
    if( line != "" ){
        ofs << line << '\n';
    }
}

ifs_1.close();
ifs_2.close();

ofs.close();
```

test:

```
cat file1
one
two
--> empty
--> empty
```

and file2:

```
cat file2:
three
four
--> empty
--> empty
```

the output:

```
cat file3
one
two
three
four
```